# I can't install opencv for python on Windows after trying out almost everything

Tags: python, opencv, pip

These are the things I tried but nothing seems to work yet

```
pip install opencv-python
```

OR

```
python -m pip install opencv-python
```

gives an error

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python (from versions: none)
>   ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv-python

I downloaded the opencv windows package from the site and copied the PYD file into python's site-packages
but still `cv2` cannot be imported

```
import cv2
```

gives an error as

> DLL load failed while importing cv2: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Then I downloaded the opecv-control WHL file for python3.8/32bit (as my python is 32 bit) unofficial Binaries for python extension packages
and followed the step but still nothing happened

I am a beginner in this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting error while installing opencv via pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58919182/getting-error-while-installing-opencv-via-pip)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenCV hasn't been built for 3.8 yet according to the docs 3.7 is the highest version

[`https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/`](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/)

try downgrading your python to 3.7 or below. It would work.

Answer (score 1):

Is pip up to date? You can run `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` to check.
It should work after that.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
import imp
imp.find_module("cv2")
```

Answer (score 0):

[Python Package Link](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

In the above link search **opencv_python‑4.1.2‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl** for python 3.6 
64 bit and download that wheel file.

Install procedures:

1. Go to the site-package path in the python36

   C:\Program Files\Python36\Lib\site-packages>
2. Then put the command pip install . Example,

   C:\Program Files\Python36\Lib\site-packages>pip install **F:\urllib3-1.25.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl**

After this procedure import and check in IDLE.

If any doubt ping this. Good luck