# getting error while installing opencv via pip

Tags: python, opencv, while-loop, installation

**python version = Python 3.8.0**

**pip version = 19.3.1**

```
C:\Users\Sami Ullah Ch>pip3 install opencv-python

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python (from versions: none)
```

[image]

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/ at the end. I don't think the package is available for 3.8. 3.8 is fairly new and packages are probably still running tests in 3.8 environments

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58918606/i-cant-install-opencv-for-python-on-windows-after-trying-out-almost-everything

Answer (score 1):

**Install OpenCV**

Refresh the packages index and install the OpenCV package by typing:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-opencv
```

The command above will install all packages necessary to run OpenCV.

**Verify the OpenCV installation**

To verify the installation we will import the cv2 module and print the OpenCV version:

```
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
```

Output

> 3.2.0

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV has not been built yet for 3.8.0. You should try using Python version 3.7